# Comparing two tables in SQL Server across databases and layers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union, union-all

I am trying to compare two tables from my DM-layer but from two different databases (old db and new db, for data consistency/comparative data analysis). To be able to compare the two tables I need to join through EDW and MDM/Maps layer. I need to compare columns and rows for a match on content and I want the content that do not match to be outputted in some way. How would you proceed with this?

So far I have this Full outer join. I was thinking about using this way of comparing for inequalities: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/10/2737.aspx

But I can't seem to get my UNION ALL working instead of the FULL OUTER JOIN. How would you proceed and would you at all use UNION ALL?

```
select * from (
select dm.*, mdm.ProductionSystem, mdm.SchoolIdent
from DM_OLD.dbo.DimSchool dm
inner join EDW_OLD.dbo.School edw on dm.EdwSchoolId = edw.SchoolID
inner join MDM_OLD.dbo.School mdm on edw.SYS_BusinessKeyFK = mdm.SYS_BusinessKeyID
) a
full outer join
(
select dm.*, maps.ProductionSystem, maps.SchoolIdent
from dm.dbo.DimSchool dm
inner join edw.dbo.School edw on dm.EdwSchoolId = edw.SchoolID
inner join edw.maps.School maps on edw.SYS_BusinessKeyFK = maps.SYS_BusinessKeyID
) b ON a.ProductionSystem = b.ProductionSystem AND a.SchoolIdent = b.SchoolIdent
```

Comment: I recently faced a similar task. I decided to use SSIS and create a C# Source Component which took care of the comparison in memory and put out the differing fields...

Answer (score 0):

This query shows you all the rows that are present in OLD and miss in NEW:

```
select dm.*, mdm.ProductionSystem, mdm.SchoolIdent
from DM_OLD.dbo.DimSchool dm
inner join EDW_OLD.dbo.School edw on dm.EdwSchoolId = edw.SchoolID
inner join MDM_OLD.dbo.School mdm on edw.SYS_BusinessKeyFK = mdm.SYS_BusinessKeyID

except

select dm.*, maps.ProductionSystem, maps.SchoolIdent
from dm.dbo.DimSchool dm
inner join edw.dbo.School edw on dm.EdwSchoolId = edw.SchoolID
inner join edw.maps.School maps on edw.SYS_BusinessKeyFK = maps.SYS_BusinessKeyID
```

And this will show you what you have in new and miss in OLD:

```
select dm.*, maps.ProductionSystem, maps.SchoolIdent
from dm.dbo.DimSchool dm
inner join edw.dbo.School edw on dm.EdwSchoolId = edw.SchoolID
inner join edw.maps.School maps on edw.SYS_BusinessKeyFK = maps.SYS_BusinessKeyID

except

select dm.*, mdm.ProductionSystem, mdm.SchoolIdent
from DM_OLD.dbo.DimSchool dm
inner join EDW_OLD.dbo.School edw on dm.EdwSchoolId = edw.SchoolID
inner join MDM_OLD.dbo.School mdm on edw.SYS_BusinessKeyFK = mdm.SYS_BusinessKeyID
```

Comment: @sepudic And then I just need to UNION ALL somehow?

Comment: Is your aim "to use union all at any cost" or to compare 2 tables?

Comment: @sepucic Only if it is the smarter solution. I want to test whether the content in the different rows matches in tables from old db and new db.

Comment: Did you try my code? if you have tbl1 with row (1,2,3) and tbl2 with (1,2,4) it will show both rows as they are different. And if both table contain only (1,2,3) it will return nothing

Comment: Running your code gives me: "Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.
"

Comment: I am thinking if you could do something like
EXCEPT
UNION ALL
EXCEPT
and then append some kind of identifier to each row to see from what DB it comes from. I want the result in one resultset - not two

Comment: This error means that DimSchool has some additional columns in old or new schema

Comment: Script your table DimSchool in both databases and find these additional columns, then don't use   dm.* but a list of COMMON columns insted